# VBA Automation Error | How to remove sheets in a excel document copy?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following Worksheet Layout

[image]

> **Now what I'm trying to do, is to create a copy of the document and keep only the two sheets `Chase_list` and `Summary`**

(I however need to change the file extension from .xlsm to .xlsx so I can't use the `SaveCopyAs` method)

I attempted doing so with the following code *(also the first line works properly, don't worry about it, variables are already defined, it's the actual worksheet deleting that does the harm*)

```
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs new_name & "_end_week_" & current_week - 1, 51, _ 
        accessMode:=xlExclusive
        Sheets("Chase_list").Cells.Copy
        Sheets("Chase_list").Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Sheets("Instructions").Delete
        Sheets("03_000002").Delete
        Sheets("Additions").Delete
        Sheets("Data").Delete
        Sheets("Control Panel").Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Basically what it does, we first paste the data in chase_list as Values (because it's linked to another sheets we're removing) and once we do so, we start removing the sheets in the newly saved .xlsx file *(maybe that fact it's not .xlsm anymore could do some harm?)*

It seems to remove the worksheets sucessfuly like so:

[image]

Unfortunately,  I am then presented with the following error

[image]

Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

> *Note: If I step through the code, it seems to crash on the last/pre-last line of code*

Comment: What line did you get the error on? The first sheet that you attempted to delete? Is the code in an Addin?

Comment: @Brian I unfortunately can't tell you, because as soon as I Save the file as .xlsx I can't step into the code with debugger. (Basically the entire VB coding area locks once the document is saved). I would however presume on the first line of the delete method.

Comment: `Control_Panel` should be `Control Panel` (space not underscore)

Comment: actually now that I think about it, it's probably also locked because the document was shared prior. Let me edit the question quickly

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that your sheet is named `Control Panel` (space) but you try to delete `Control_Panel` (underscore):

**Compare:**
[image]

```
                                                            Sheets("Control_Panel").Delete
'                                                       space vs undersore ^
```

---

**Improvement:**
You can use a loop to delete all sheets besides `Chase_list` and `Summary`

```
Dim sh As Variant
For Each sh In Sheets
    If sh.Name <> "Chase_list" And sh.Name <> "Summary" Then
        sh.Delete
    End If
Next sh
```

---

**Alternative:**

If the error persists try to copy the worksheets into a new workbook and save that.

```
Sheets(Array("Chase_list", "Summary")).Copy
With ActiveWorkbook
    Sheets("Chase_list").Cells.Copy
    Sheets("Chase_list").Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    .SaveAs
End With
```

Comment: Hey, apologies for the late edit. I did change the code a little, fixed the `Control Panel` naming issue and also turned off Shared Document for easier debugging - (the worksheet removal seems to work now), but I got greeted with another uncomely error. Please revise again (but thanks for the answer anyways)!

Comment: @Rawrplus - probably you have to check how many sheets you have before deleting them.

Comment: @Vityata, All the sheets in the picture + 1 Hidden sheet (which I'm not removing either). The algorhytm for removing is the same as the one  in my edited question (what I mean under that, I'm not using the For Each and removing any sheets by accident, which would cause the error)

Comment: does the code run from a button on the `Control Panel` sheet? If yes, this might cause the error when you delete that sheet.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Yes it does, Probably should have disclosed that. My bad. Any suggestion on how to avoid that error? Technically I can create a procedure, but still need it ultimately to be invoked from the button, from the sheet `Control Panel` which will  also be ultimately deleted. As to my knowledge, VBA is not capable of callback functions/procedures(?)

Comment: @Rawrplus I'm not sure if this really is the issue. This was just a guess. Test it by moving the button (and eventually its code, if not in a module) onto `Summary` for example (just for testing).

Comment: @PEH Actually no, unfortunately doesn't look like it's bound to the sheet / button being removed. I fired the code from a separate procedure which I ran manually and I still got the same error

Comment: I guess I could surpress the error with `On Error Resume ... `, given the functionality of it seems to be fine (it deletes the sheets like it's supposed to) but I still am genuinely curious as to what is causing this error.

Comment: @Rawrplus Another guess: The issue might be that the code was started in the "xlsm" and then got saved as "xlsx" while the "xlsm" closes but its code is still running? Try instead to copy the workbooks into a new sheet `Sheets(Array("Chase_list", "Summary")).Copy` then replace formula to values and then save as.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ That's kind of an issue. I need all the sheets in my original document. (It's a pretty robust file with formulas and what not) - so basically I can only manipulate with the newly create .xlsx file, but I can under no condition replace as values / delete everything in the original.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Though one thing I tried. I took out the `51` out of my first `Save As` line, to basically create a renamed copy of my .xlsm file, then I executed all the commands in my newly created .xlsm  and then at the very bottom I just added the same `Save As` line, this time including the `51` file type. Stil lgot the error

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are trying to delete a sheet, which is the last one in Excel. And Excel returns `1004`, when you try to do something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim arrNames As Variant
    arrNames = Array("Chase_list", "Summary")

    For Each wks In Worksheets
        If Not valueInArray(wks.Name, arrNames) Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            If Sheets.Count > 1 Then wks.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    Next wks

End Sub

Public Function valueInArray(myValue As Variant, myArray As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim cnt As Long

    For cnt = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        If CStr(myValue) = CStr(myArray(cnt)) Then
            valueInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next cnt

End Function
```

You loop through the `Worksheets` and if you have more than 1 `Sheets` left, the `wks` is deleted. The `valueInArray()` is a boolean function, returning info whether the value was found in array.